# "Greater part" versus "Best part" describing duration?

Tags: meaning

> "The delegations from Beauxbatons and Durmstrang will be arriving in October and remaining with us for the **greater part** of this year. I know that you will all extend every courtesy to our foreign guests while they are with us, and will give your whole-hearted support to the Hogwarts champion when he or she is selected.
>
> — Harry Potter

Does the meaning of *greater part of a duration* the same as *best part of a duration*?
which both means the ***most part of a duration***? Will the meaning change if the above quote is changed into "best part of this year"?

Comment: I think it means *the most part of the year*. But I've not read HP so cannot say anything precisely. Maybe, the greater part of the year is remaining as they have some important celebration?

Comment: Sure, they had those big things coming up—the Tourna and the ball. Maybe it could mean both. I have added more context for the quote.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the meaning change if the above quote is changed into "best part of this year"?

No. The meaning will stay the same.

However, the **best part** of the year can also mean *the part of the year I like most*, as in

1 June is the best part of the year. I like it the most.
2 Summer is the best part of the year. I like it the most.
3 September through May is the best part of the year. I like it the most, because that is when school is in session and I love school.

Note that *Greater part of the year* does not mean *the part of the year I like most.* So, you will change the meaning of the Sentence 3 if you use *the greater part of the year.* With *greater part* it will mean *longer part* or *the more long part*; and it can be equivalent to *the most long part*, depending on the length of the duration you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The "greater part" of the year is the larger part; in other words, more than half.

The "best part" of the year can mean the larger part, but it can also mean the most favourable part.

If it's important to avoid that ambiguity, use "greater part" for the larger part and "best *time*" for the most favourable time ("Autumn is the best time of the year").

Answer (score 0):

In my decades of experience being an American, Americans rarely (if ever) use "the best part of the year" to mean anything *but* "the part of the year I like best." (So if you say "he stayed for the best part of the year," your listeners will almost always expect you to tell them what you consider the best part of the year to be, such as summer, winter, spring, or autumn.) Personally, I would say you should *never* use "the best part of [a duration]" when speaking to Americans, unless you mean the part you like best. Some might understand what you mean, but I think most would not.

Americans may say "the better part of the year" and *usually* mean "the larger half of a year." Saying "the greater part of the year" or "the larger part of the year" or "most of the year" would also be understood, without the ambiguity of using "better" (which could also mean better-versus-worse).